# how to create a new object element in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, element

I'm struggling to understand what I'm doing wrong here.

I have an empty object:

```
if ( doc._attachments === undefined ){
    doc._attachments = {};
}
var attmtid = 123;
```

which I'm trying to populate like so:

```
doc._attachments[attmtid].revpos = "abc";
```

However I keep getting an undefined error from Firebug:

```
doc._attachments[attmtid] is undefined
```

And can't really make any sense of it.

**Question:**
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`doc._attachments[attmtid]` is undefined, which means you need to define it as something.  An array, an object, a string, etc.  For example, you could make it another object:

```
doc._attachments[attmtid] = {};
```

And then be able to set properties on that object:

```
doc._attachments[attmtid].revpos = "abc";
```

Comment: Ok. I got it. I guess I need to define both `_doc.attachments` and `_doc.attachments[123]` which makes sense since I need to keep track of different attachments to a single document.

Comment: @frequent You probably want to do the same `undefined` check for `_doc.attachments[attmtid]` before initializing, so you don't overwrite other properties.

Comment: @frequent - Yup, you got it.  You can't go around setting properties on an undefined object.  For example: `var x = {}; x.y.z = 1;` isn't going to work.

Answer (score 6):

Why not do:

```
doc._attachments[attmtid] = {
    revpos: "abc"
};
```

Answer (score 2):

`doc._attachments[attmtid]` is not initialized to an object so you cannot dynamically assign the revpos property.

This should resolve it:

```
doc._attachments[attmtid] = {};
doc._attachments[attmtid].revpos = "abc";
```

Note: This is based on the expectation that you want a `doc._attachments.123` property (which is what the example code in the question would create) and not a `doc._attachments.attmid` property.

Comment: Probably want to check if `doc._attachments[attmtid]` is `undefined` first - only if it is, then initialize it with `{}`. Then always set the `revpos` property.